# How can I create a searchable attribute for a page on Confluence wiki?

Tags: wiki, confluence

I want to create a page in my confluence wiki which has a searchable attribute.  Right now search is limited to the pages text, and then filtering using tags.  It would be great if I could filter further based on defined page attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just add specific labels to that page .. e.g. *"info1"* and *"info2"*. Afterwards you're able to search for that page using the normal Confluence search and searching for `labelText:info1 and labelText:info2`.

Another choice is using a combination of the [Metadata Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/5295) and the [Reporting Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/186) together - they are both available for free at Atlassian's Plugin Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw this response now. :-)

Comment: @llawliet You're welcome! Meanwhile, Atlassian has created a new API called _content properties_, might also be a solution for you here:
https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/content-properties-in-the-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SQL query](https://wikitechcomm.onconfluence.com/display/CONF/Searching+Confluence+storage+format+XML+for+content+or+markup) to search the Confluence storage format (XML source) of your pages.